# Model giving accuracy of 89% after training it by CT scan Images. and giving accuracy of 35% on testing. and low precision, recall, f1-score

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, conv-neural-network, image-processing

I am training a model for cancer detection by using chest CT scan Image. training set is 70% testing set is 20% validation set is 10%.

Data contain 3 chest cancer types which are Adenocarcinoma, Large cell carcinoma, Squamous cell carcinoma , and 1 folder for the normal cell.

Model giving accuracy of 89% after training it by CT scan Images. and giving accuracy of 35% on testing and validation. and low precision, recall, f1-score.

Here is the code:

```
 res_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, 
                         pooling='avg', 
                         weights='imagenet', 
                         input_shape = (IMAGE_SHAPE))

    for layer in res_model.layers:
        if 'conv5' not in layer.name:
            layer.trainable = False
with strategy.scope(): #use TPU/GPU strategy
    
    res_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, 
                         pooling='avg', 
                         weights='imagenet', 
                         input_shape = (IMAGE_SHAPE))

    for layer in res_model.layers:
        if 'conv5' not in layer.name:
            layer.trainable = False

    resnet_model = Sequential()
    resnet_model.add(res_model)
    resnet_model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    resnet_model.add(Flatten())
    resnet_model.add(BatchNormalization())
    resnet_model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    resnet_model.add(Dense(N_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
    resnet_model.summary()

    adam_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate= 0.00001, 
                                         decay= 1e-5)
    #compiling the model
    resnet_model.compile(optimizer=adam_optimizer, 
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                         metrics=['accuracy']) #need to update to use f1 score too
print(resnet_model.summary())
```

on uploading image to model it is not predicting the correct class which the image belongs to or the type of cancer it have.

I'm using ResNet50 for training and Adam optimizer. i have also tried it with vgg16.

it is not predicting the correct type of cancer cell name on uploading image to it.

Most of the time its giving wrong name.

I thing that happening because the accuracy, precision, recall, f1-score is low on testing and validation.

i dont know how to increase its accuracy and what to do so it can predict the correct class of image.

any suggestion for increasing the test & validation accuracy and improving the confusion matrix graph. so it can give more accurate prediction on uploading image to the model ??

Comment: Are you using a Kaggle (competition) dataset? If yes, looking at how others approached the competion/dataset might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when you overfit the training data. Your model identifies idiosyncratic characteristics of the training data that are specific to that data sample but don't generalize to other data samples. So what seems to be excellent performance on the training data does not carry over to new data.

[An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com) discusses overfitting and how to minimize it throughout the text. Considerations specific to neural networks are in Chapter 10. In outline, to minimize overfitting you can either have the network learn more slowly or penalize the model's parameters.

Also, consider whether a single train/test split is the best way to evaluate your modeling. In other contexts [Frank Harrell recommends resampling-based validation](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/) of the modeling process unless you have tens of thousands of cases. I suspect that similar considerations apply to this type of image classification, although I don't have much experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

you described your method extensively but haven't gone through the data and sampling. Is your data balanced? I am guessing not. If so, then looking at the accuracy may be misleading. Usually, the misleading is in one direction - you'd see high accuracy, even though your model hasn't learned anything. Since, from your description, you have such stark differences, the obvious suspect is overfitting. But before you go on, it is good to verify for yourself *that your datasets have the same distribution*. This is actually an assumption, otherwise, you can't really tell if your model learned anything. You are using ResNet, which is a huge network, and therefore you probably have too high variance in your model. Your model is very good for predicting examples from your training set since having such high variance allows it to fit itself to the training data. The first and easiest thing to do is to regularize your model. Start by adding a penalty to weights, I would go with L1, since where you're at, you might want to "turn off" buttons in the network. Second, I would also add dropout. You should expect a decrease in your performance on your training, accompanied by an increase in your performance on the test set.
Other, less trivial approaches would be to get more data. In case your data is too small, then your model after training on such a small training set is failing to generalize to new data (even if your targets have the same distribution across your samples.
Another, last piece of advice, keep your test aside, don't look at it. You don't want to contaminate your work.

Comment: if i m using regularization l1 then the accuracy of the model is decreasing to 30%. , i dont know what to do now.

Comment: I wrote multiple points there. Have you gone through anything? How many examples do you have of each of the classes? I suspect that you just don't have enough data for such huge model. Also, are your samples have the same distribution across multiple labels?